# Case no order by

Tags: sql, firebird

Estou tentando fazer um order by conforme o resultado do sql:

```
sql.... 
order by cod_rua,
 case cod_lado
     when 'M' then cod_lado desc
     else cod_lado ASC
 end, cod_altura
```

Só que esta dando erro no desc.

Pessoal não deu certo:

```
order by
 r.cod_altura, r.nr_rua,
 (case when tb_confcamara.cod_lado =  'M' then r.cod_posicao) desc,
 (case when tb_confcamara.cod_lado <> 'M' then r.cod_posicao)
```

Seguinte Erro:

```
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 21, column 60.
)
```

Estou utilizando Firebird.

Comment: Se `cod_lado` for = 'M' você quer ordenar a coluna decrescente, se não crescente?

Comment: Thiago, está [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486882/case-when-statement-for-order-by-clause) do SO-En vai lhe ajudar, só não sei como isso se aplica no Banco firebird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separe corretamente suas colunas com o auxílio do `case`.
É importante destacar que não poderá haver ambiguidade nas condições.

Cada coluna (os `cases`) receberão a palavra chave `DESC` ou `ASC`.

*Obs: Informar a palavra chave `ASC` é opcional.*

```
sql.... 
order by cod_rua,
         (case when cod_lado = 'M' then cod_lado) desc,
         (case when cod_lado <> 'M' then cod_lado),
         cod_altura
```

Answer (score 1):

```
order by cod_rua,
 (case cod_lado
     when 'M' then cod_lado 
     else cod_lado ASC
 end) desc, 
cod_altura
```

O "case" é uma coluna o "desc" vem depois.